# Reponsive Media-queries issues break dragging the browser into smaller size

Tags: media-queries

Why my media query break when making the browser smaller the width but in the inspect element my media query is responsive?

Comment: Please add your existing media query and relevant HTML to help debug your issue

Comment: I already added my media query the problem is when used to drag smaller the browser it breaks but when I use inspect element to reduce the screen size my media query works.